# Emacs org mode is exporting a blank pdf on OSX (possibly due to missing fonts)

Tags: emacs, org-mode, tex

I have the org-mode installed and I am trying to export the .org file to pdf. I have the Basic Tex installed and have set the PATH env variable correctly.

When I give this command C-c C-e p, I get the message "Exporting to pdf done", however, the generated pdf is blank.

So it seems, there is something going wrong when I am trying from emacs. There is also a missfont.log file.

Googling for answers is not getting me anywhere. Please help as I am stuck on this problem for quite a while. I initially gave on it, but using org mode for generating pdfs is so productive that I simply cannot live without it. I have this in my office RHEL box working fine. Only at home on my Mac, it is giving me issues

Comment: Emacs on OSX doesn't automatically pick-up the regular $PATH that would be seen in the Terminal.app.  On Snow Leopard 10.6.8, I use this line in my `.emacs` file -- just adjust the path accordingly to wherever you have installed your `*.tex` stuff:  `(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/texbin"))`  If you want to see what Emacs thinks your $PATH is before you add this line of code, you can type `M-x eval-expression RET (getenv "PATH") RET`; and, you can do the same thing again after you add the line of code and restart Emacs to make sure it is correct.

Comment: I have passed all that stage and got over these hurdles, actually i think the problem is missingfonts. I can see the missingfont.log containing mktextfm ecrm1095
mktextfm ectt1000
mktextfm ecrm1728

Comment: Are those fonts present in your Basic Tex installation?  If so, then the issue is probably the $PATH even though you are certain it's not.  If the fonts are not present, then install them.

Comment: If storage space is not an issue, perhaps consider installing TeXLive:  https://tug.org/mactex/  Alternatively, a little Googling revealed methods of installing your missing fonts -- e.g., using curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing fonts did the trick, I needed to install ec and wasy2